# Developing a jQuery plugin that returns a given object, instead of jQuery object itself!

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Consider the following base code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(settings) {
        return this.each(function() {
            //whatever
        });
    };
});
```

The plugin returns a jQuery object. The question is how am I supposed to write a plugin that returns a custom object so that I can do something like this:

```
var api = $('div.myelement').myPlugin();
api.onMyEventName(function(e, whateverParam) {
    //whatever
});
```

It'd be highly appreciated if you could write some lines of code that describes me how to do that, how to call the onMyEventName function on a custom api object...

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you just return your object?

Comment: It might brake the JQuery design contract, better to ask.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
(function($) {
    function MyApi($this, settings) {
        this.$this = $this;
        this.settings = settings;
    };

    MyApi.prototype.output = function (val) {
       // use this.$this to access the original jQuery object

       return this.settings[val];
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(settings) {
        return new MyApi(this, settings);
    };
});
```

**Note** that we've passed `this` from `$.fn.myPlugin()` into the `MyApi` constructor; this allows you to access the jQuery object that `myPlugin()` was originally called on within `MyApi` methods.

You can also do the same using the object literal syntax:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(settings) {
        return {
            settings: settings,
            output: function (val) {
                // use this.$this to access the original jQuery object

                return this.settings[val];
            },
            $this: this
        };
    };
});
```

Then;

```
var something = $('#something').myPlugin({
   val: 'Lemon'
});

alert(something.output('val')); // Lemon
```

... again, we've captured the value of `this` (the jQuery object) into a property `$this` on the newly constructed objected, to gain access to the original jQuery object.

Comment: Assuming you are accessing your object through JQuery selectors because they are related to the selected nodes, the `$.fn.myPlugin` should provide the nodes (`this`) to the MyApi ctor. Also `$.fn.myPlugin` should use $.map(this,...) so that all the items matched by the selector would be processed with MyApi...

Comment: @VajkHermecz: it was a bit of a contrived example I used, but non-the-less you are right about normally passing `this`; I've updated the code accordingly. In terms of using `map()` (infact, `each()` is more common), I'll leave that to the reader to see whether they need it or not; it depends on the usecase!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [great article by Hector Virgen](http://www.virgentech.com/blog/2009/10/building-object-oriented-jquery-plugin.html) detailing a possible solution (also used in bootstrap) to adress this question.

The key moment is basically storing your API object in the data section of the node:

```
$.fn.myplugin = function() {
    return $.each(function() {
        ...
        myplugin = new MyPlugin(this)
        ...
        $(this).data('myplugin', myplugin);
    }
}
```

After this, users can easily access the object by:

```
$(this).data("myplugin")
```

A possibly useful extension to this solution could be defining a `mypluginapi` method as a shorthand, for accessing your API object:

```
$.fn.mypluginapi = function() {
    return $(this).myplugin().data('myplugin')
}
```